# How can I create a golden master for mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I was wondering how to create a [golden master approach](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/02/20/gold-master-testing/) to start creating some tests for my MVC 4 application.

> "Gold master testing refers to capturing the result of a process, and
>   then comparing future runs against the saved “gold master” (or known
>   good) version to discover unexpected changes." - [@brynary](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/02/20/gold-master-testing/)

Its a large application with no tests and it will be good to start development with the golden master to ensure the changes we are making to increase the test coverage and hopefully decrease the complexity in the long don't break the application.

I am think about capturing a days worth of real world traffic from the IIS logs and use that to create the golden master however I am not sure the easiest or best way to go about it. There is nothing out of the ordinary on the app lots controllers with post backs etc

I am looking for a way to create a suitable golden master for a MVC 4 application hosted in IIS 7.5.

**NOTES**
To clarify something in regards to the comments the "golden master" is a test you can run to verify output of the application. It is like journalling your application and being able to run that journal every time you make a change to ensure you have broken anything.

> When working with legacy code, it is almost impossible to understand
>   it and to write code that will surely exercise all the logical paths
>   through the code. For that kind of testing, we would need to
>   understand the code, but we do not yet. So we need to take another
>   approach.
>
> Instead of trying to figure out what to test, we can test everything,
>   a lot of times, so that we end up with a huge amount of output, about
>   which we can almost certainly assume that it was produced by
>   exercising all parts of our legacy code. It is recommended to run the
>   code at least 10,000 (ten thousand) times. We will write a test to run
>   it twice as much and save the output.
>
> Patkos Csaba - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/refactoring-legacy-code-part-1-the-golden-master--cms-20331

My question is how do I go about doing this to a MVC application.

Regards

Comment: I dont think this post is off topic

Comment: Down vote negated - I think this is a legitimately good question, but you should provide some specific areas of your application that you're looking to test using this approach.

Comment: well the purpose of the golden master is to test the whole output i.e. all responses from the server for a given number of request. They can never change the responses they must be identical to ensure the golden master test pass.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to compare two large sets of results and control variations, in practice, an integration test. I believe that the real traffic can't exactly give you the control that I think you need it.

Before making any change to the production code, you should do the following:

1. **Create X number of random inputs, always using the same random seed, so you can generate always the same set over and over again. You will probably want a few thousand random inputs.**
2. **Bombard the class or system under test with these random inputs.**
3. **Capture the outputs for each individual random input**

When you run it for the first time, record the outputs in a file (or database, etc). From then on, you can start changing your code, run the test and compare the execution output with the original output data you recorded. If they match, keep refactoring, otherwise, revert back your change and you should be back to green.

This doesn't match with your approach. Imagine a scenario in which a user makes a purchase of a certain product, you can not determine the outcome of the transaction, insufficient credit, non-availability of the product, so you cannot trust in your input.

However, what you now need is a way to replicate that data automatically, and the automation of the browser in this case cannot help you much.

You can try a different approach, something like the [**Lightweight Test Automation Framework**](https://ltaf.codeplex.com/) or else [**MvcIntegrationTestFramework**](https://github.com/JonCanning/MvcIntegrationTestFramework/) which are the most appropriate to your scenario

Comment: Ok I will have a try and see what i can get out of these frameworks.